# mongoexport using python subprocess fails - no reacahble serves

Tags: python, docker, subprocess, mongoexport

I have a docker container (based on RHEL6) where I am running the `mongoexport` command line tool from a python script using the `subprocess` module.

`mongoexport` fails with exit code 1 and the error:

```
no reachable servers
```

The `mongoexport` command has the required connection info, such as host, port, db.

When I run the same `mongoexport` command in the same container using `docker run`, it succeeds.

Any idea what goes wrong when I run using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to linux/windows compatibility and the way the `mongoexport` command is built.

The developer developed the Python script on Windows, where `subprocess.Popen` can receive the command line as a string array. In linux, however, it should be a single string argument.

Changing the way the argument passed to `subprocess.Popen` to a single string fixed this problem.